# How to setup environment for BlackBerry in-app payment tests?

Tags: testing, blackberry, in-app-purchase, payment

I'm trying to implement [in-app payment](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Payment%20Service) support in a BB application.

Ok, I've read the API/docs and now I need to write a simple test. Here is what API says about testing:

> To test the end-to-end purchase flow without being charged money, you can set up a BlackBerry ID as a test account. The test account allows you to download any applications or digital goods that are associated with your BlackBerry App World vendor account without incurring any costs. Local testing must be turned off for this type of testing, otherwise no network connections will be attempted.

From the above I see that I need to achieve 2 goals:

- (1) "set up a BlackBerry ID as a test account" (what ever it means).
- (2) "Local testing must be turned off for this type of testing" (what ever it means).

The API is vague on how to do that. I can only guess that point (1) can be done on the side of my customer (whom I'm writing the app for) via his AppWorld account. Is it true? And I'm totally out of ideas on point (2). Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What about debugging the application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah yes, the Payment API is particularly vague on testing, and in the latest version (1.5) RIM have removed the ability to test locally, so all testing must be done via App World. Here's how:

1. Setup a 'sandbox' account using the [BlackBerry App World vendor portal](https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do)
2. Upload your app into BlackBerry App world but **don't publish it**, just save it and leave it in draft state
3. Also in the vendor portal, set up your digital goods (the things available for in-app purchase)
4. On your BlackBerry, load App World and login with your sandbox account email address.
5. Within any screen in App World press ALT+TST and enter the SKU or ID of your test app.
6. You can then download the test version of your app (which is not available to anyone else)
7. Once the app is downloaded and installed you will be able to test your in app payments.

Bit of a faff, but not too hard once you've got the process sorted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick and helpful response! Is it true that if I install my app on the simulator in a way I usually do it while developing (I load .cod file via simulator menu item), then I will not be able to test the in-app payments (even if my simulator has AppWorld of a required version)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To test in app payments, the app itself MUST be installed using App World.

Comment: And once installed using App World, can the app be then updated via "load .cod file" simulator's menu item? I suspect no, but just to be 100% clear.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, the app must be installed using App World.

Comment: I would add info about the use of the Playbook. The point 5) of this list should be changed with the following: 
5) Open App World. Swipe the finger from the bottom-left to the center to open the keyboard. Type "tst" (nothing will happen, it's fine). While leaving BlackBerry World open, head on over to your browser and type in the webstore URL for your application (http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/NUMERICAL-ID), change the ID with the one of your app. The browser should start loading a web page and quickly shift back into BlackBerry World and open your application. Download it.